# Why must block be copied and not retained? When do you not need to copy a block?

Tags: ios, block, objective-c-blocks

Why must block be copied and not retained? What is difference between the two under the hood?
Under what condition do you not need to copy a block, if any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually when you allocate an instance of a class, it goes in the heap and sticks around until it gets deallocated. But if you declare a block inline with code, it goes on the stack. When the stack frame goes away, so does the block instance-- unless you copy it, which creates a heap-resident instance. Basically, if you want to continue using the block after the stack frame gets popped, you need to make a copy somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. When do you not need to copy a block?

Comment: Mostly when someone else is doing it for you, e.g. if you're calling a block-based API that makes the copy internally. It's also possible to declare static blocks just like you'd declare a function, standalone in code rather than inline. Those will be on the heap and won't need to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are created on the stack and destroyed when execution reaches the end of the current scope. To prevent this from happening you have to copy them which causes them to be copied to the heap. Usually you would copy a block you want to call it at some later point, outside of the scope where it was created.